# Android: setImageUri failing

Tags: android, listview, uri

My application has an insert activity that has an image picker and the Uri from that is stored as a string ready to put into a database.

```
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data) {
    if(resCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if(reqCode == 1) {
            imageUri = data.getData().toString();
        }
    }
}
```

imageUri is the String that is then later put in a database on a button press.

Once everything is inserted into the database the activity finishes to return the main activity which in the `onResume`method all the data from the database/table is retrieved in a List of objects that are then put into a custom array adapter to form my list view.

```
if(!uriString.equals("")) {
     image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(uriString));
}
```

This is how the image is set inside the array adapter. The strange thing is that right after the insert activity closes the image is visible but as soon as I open another activity and return the image is blank. I get the error

```
resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A29938
```

I don't know why it can't be resolved because it is fine to start with but then it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content URI's need to be parsed properly as they are not like normal filePath and hence we need some resolver. Here is an example how to approach this:

Changes to your code

```
if(!uriString.equals("")) {
     image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(getPathFromURI(<your app context>, Uri.parse("content://blah/blah/blah"))));
}
```

Method definition for the URI parser.

```
public String getPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
   Cursor mediaCursor = null;
   try { 
           String[] dataPath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
           mediaCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  dataPath, null, null, null);
           int column_index = mediaCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
           mediaCursor.moveToFirst();
           return mediaCursor.getString(column_index);
   } finally {
       if (mediaCursor != null) {
             mediaCursor.close();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how I can provide the second argument, I only have the value of the URI.toString(). I tried converting it back to a URI with Uri.parse but that yields a crash

Comment: Updated the section, idea is you pass the content string in Uri format to the method. Your issue is related to get the Uri from the "content://" path into the imageview, which can be solved after getting a true path from the "content://" path.