# App crashed when using setImageURI function in ImageView

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-imageview, imageurl

I am opening the gallery and getting the URI of an image when it is selected. Then I show the picture using setImageURI like this.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == ACTION_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE){
        val uri: Uri? = data?.data
        imageUri = uri.toString()
        show_iv.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imageUri)) // handle chosen image
    }
}
```

It shows the correct image in my imageView (show_iv).
However, when I save the URI then open the file show that image again, the app crashes.

```
override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    val title = et_title.text.toString()
    if (title.length == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "The note can not be saved when the title be blank",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        if (imageUri == null)
        {
            fp.addNote(et_title.getText().toString(),
                et_body.getText().toString() + "img:" + "null",
                !isTitleExist(title))
        }
        else 
        {
            fp.addNote(et_title.getText().toString(),
                et_body.getText().toString() + "img:" + imageUri,
                !isTitleExist(title));
        }
    }
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_noteeditor)

    et_title = findViewById(R.id.et_title);
    et_body = findViewById(R.id.et_body);

    //        add picture
    val btn_addphoto: Button = findViewById(R.id.btn_addphoto)
    btn_addphoto.setOnClickListener{add_photo()}


    show_iv = findViewById(R.id.show_iv)
    show_iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.galleryicon)


    val intent = getIntent()
    val notepos = intent.getIntExtra("NOTEPOS",
        -1)

    fp = FileProcessor(this, MainActivity.EXTERNAL)
    titlelist = fp.getNoteList()

    if (notepos != -1) {
        var title = titlelist[notepos]
        et_title.setText(title)
        title = title + ".txt"
        val content = fp.readFile(title)
        val (newContent,scanUri) = content.split("img:")
        et_body.setText(newContent)
        imageUri = scanUri
        if (imageUri == "null")
            show_iv.setImageURI(null)
        else
            show_iv.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imageUri))

    } else {
        et_title.setText("")
        et_body.setText("")
    }
}
```

I use the same way to show the picture, and have checked that the URI is same in the two situation. How does it happen?

Comment: setImageURI(uri);. Use your uri.

Comment: lookout this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/38979085/12709358

Comment: Have you implemented the `FileProvider`?
Check this out: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider